# Issue with : Extension method must be static

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, c#-4.0

I have this error.

First Error:

> Extension method must be static

Second Error:

> 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetClientItemId' and no extension method 'GetClientItemId' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to apply static to my parent class like:

Before -

```
public partial class pgRPhase : Window
```

After -

```
public static partial class pgRPhase : Window
```

But I then receive other errors and issues.

WPF Coding -

```
private async Task LoadRep(TruckServiceClient TSC, ComboBox combobox)
{

        List<ClientItems> clientItems = new List<ClientItems>();            
        foreach (var rep in await TSC.GetRepByCompAsync())                
        clientItems.Add(new ClientItems { Id = rep.Id, Name = rep.Name, Contact = rep.ContactNumber, Email = rep.Email, CompanyId = rep.CompanyId });
        combobox.ItemsSource = (clientItems.ToArray().Where(x => x.CompanyId == cbCustomer.GetClientItemId()));
        combobox.IsEnabled = true;
        combobox.SelectedIndex = 1;

        combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Id";

}

public static int GetClientItemId(this ComboBox combobox)
{
    if (combobox.SelectedItem == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return ((ClientItems)combobox.SelectedItem).Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your `GetClientItemId` in a separate class and make that class `static`. (Extension methods require to be in a static class)

By making your `Window` class static, you break your entire code (you can't instantiate an instance of the window, which is required for WPF to work). If you split off the method, it will work.

Note: making this an extension method is nice, but it would probably work good enough when you make it just a regular method that is called through `GetClientItemId(cbCustomer)`. Then you don't need another class.

Comment: For the second note: there *is* an await: `foreach (var rep in await TSC.GetRepByCompAsync())`. (It may not have been there when you wrote that, admittedly...)